# wordpress website is showing 404 for non-www queries

Tags: python, django, wordpress, apache

I am having a django python website in domain.com. I am having a blog in a folder called as fmblog inside my public html. I want to access blog by entering domain.com/blog.

My blog is situated in /home/user/public_html/fmblog

So, I have an alias in my virtualhost configuration like the following.

```
Alias /blog /home/user/public_html/fmblog/
```

My issue is that, I am getting the blog when I try to access www.domain.com/blog. I am getting a 404 error when I try to access http://domain.com/blog.

Why is this happening? I know this will be fixed if I redirect every non-www requests to www using a rewrite rule. But I dont want to use that as it have some bad effects in my django website. How can I make my blog live even on non-www queries?

Comment: can you explain how Wordpress is related to python or Django?

Comment: It is not related in anyway. Actually, My main website is in django. I just want a blog for my main website which is running in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a redirect for the blog only, adding the rule to the .htaccess in the fmblog, above the #BEGIN WordPress line